# Understanding Python index operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I don't really understand index operations, can you explain what this line doing:

```
train = data[ranks>=test_points]
```

in this function

```
def random_split(data,test_points):
 ranks = np.arange(data.shape[0])     
 np.random.shuffle(ranks)         
 train = data[ranks>=test_points]

 return train
```

So I need to split data like this: half the points for training, one quarter for validation and one quarter for test. So I did it like this:

```
def random_split(data,test_points):
 ranks = np.arange(data.shape[0])     
 np.random.shuffle(ranks)         
 train = data[ranks>=test_points]

 other = data[ranks<test_points]         
 test = other[ranks>=int(test_points/4)]
 valid = other[ranks<int(test_points/4)]  
 return train,test,valid
```

It doesn't work, what is wrong? Can you help me to understand this code?

Comment: Maybe post the error message?

Comment: IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 39 but corresponding boolean dimension is 78 (test_points=39)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that after `other = data[ranks<test_points]`, the variables `other` and `rank` do not have the same size anymore, so you get an error. You could use something like

```
  train_size = 500
  validation_size = 100

  train_set = data[:train_size]
  validation_set = data[train_size: train_size + validation_size]
  test_set = data[train_size + validation_size:]
```

Note: The `x[ i < 10]` style indexing is numpy specific. It is not allowed in general python. The `<` is overloaded to return a boolean array, eg

```
i = np.array([1, 3, 5, 4])
i <= 4 # return [True True False True]
```

It's called *logical indexing* in numpy.

Comment: Can you explain what operator "<" do when it's inside of array brackets ?